# Spring Boot App keeps creating a new database Tables

Tags: java, database, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jdbc

So I have an entity that is backed up by Hibernate annotations, but the problem is whenever I do a complete restart of my app, the data in the tables gets lost.

The entity file is:

```
package hello;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your database?

Answer (score 2):

In your Applications.properties file add :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

This will use your existing table, instead of destroying and creating new table every time you restart your spring boot application.